# Html tags selection using Regex

Tags: jquery, html, css-selectors, web-component

I have a web-components guide which has a list of web-components constructed with the next name's pattern:

- `mkk-textfield`
- `mkk-textarea`
- `mkk-counter`
- `mkk-checkbox`
- ...

All of them, as you can see, starts with **mkk-** prefix and all of them have an `input` tag inside.

I have to validate some stuff with *Ajax* and *jQuery* and add some attributes and classes at the `mkk-whatever` component (not at the nested input) depending on this validation.

Example:

(Before validation)

```
<mkk-textfield label="Text">
    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Text" />
</mkk-textfield>
```

(After validation)

```
<mkk-textfield label="Text" class="someClass error" error-message="My custom error message">
    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Text" />
</mkk-textfield>
```

Is there a way to select a tag with *jQuery* matching a pattern like a regex? Something like *jQuery* selectors but for the tag:

The next example is for select all divs his name attribute starts with or contains the word *value* : 
`div[name|=”value”]` or `div[name~=”value”]`

But in my case I would like to do something like `mkk.*` which selects all tags matching the regex.

The point is, all of them can't have id, so, I need to do that in order to use something like `closest` function and, at this point, select the one with mkk- which can be a textfield a counter or whatever.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE** for a complete example. I have a form with three web components:

```
<mkk-textfield label="Text">
    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Text" />
</mkk-textfield>

<mkk-datepicker label="MyDate">
    <input type="date" value="" placeholder="Text" />
</mkk-textfield>

<mkk-radio label="MyRadio">
    <input type="radio" value="" />
</mkk-textfield>
```

All this web-components 'explode' in the DOM with divs and labels inside, for example, the textfield is:

```
<mm-textfield label="Name" class="hydrated">
    <label>Name</label>
    <div class="input-content">
        <input id="name" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter your name" name="name">    
   </div><
/mm-textfield>
```

When submit (validate ajax call) is done I receive in my jQuery function all the form fields and a message, so, the addError function is executed once per form field:

```
function addError(field, message){
    // Do the magic to figure out which mkk web component is the closest one
    $(/*PUT HERE THIS STACKOVERFLOW SOLUTION*/).attr("error-message", message).addClass("error");
}
```

I could resolve it with ifs and parent().parent() dependening on the mkk-component because each one has different html nested tags, but I wrote this question in order to do it in a more elegant way.

Hope this helps to better understand the problem.

Comment: Based on your update it sounds like `closest()` could be a solution, but it depends on how the `addError()` function is called and/or what `field` is a reference to

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan here https://pastebin.com/ZBZHYN4C is the fragment of the code where the first addError param comes from

Answer (score 0):

You should never use Regex to parse HTML. If you're using jQuery already then you can use that to parse the HTML string and amend it as required using the methods available; `attr()` and `addClass()` in this case:

```js
var $tags = $('<mkk-textfield label="Text" class="someClass error" error-message="My custom error message"><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Text" /></mkk-textfield>');
$tags.filter('mkk-textfield').attr('error-message', 'My custom error message').addClass('someClass error');

// testing
console.log($tags.get(0).outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Maybe we should have a canonical answer that we could link to to show how bad parsing HTML with regexes is. ;)

Comment: There is already (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), but I thought in this case I'd give the OP a workable alternative with an example.

Comment: No useful for my needs. The point is, it's done dinamically, I don't know which field (mkk component) I have to parse. I just recieve a field (input) and I want to reach his mkk parent and add the classes and error-message without doing it by something like parent().parent() [I need two parents in some cases because of the label but in radio or select is different, thats why I need to know the closest mkk component.

Comment: I've updated with a clear example in order to understand it better.